How do I quickly create empty vertex groups for a collection of specific bones?
I just want to be able to select a few specific bones and create empty vertex groups for them. This way I can select the specific vertices I want to weight paint in edit mode, click on the vertex group I want, and press assign to neatly weight paint certain areas. I know that, if I weight paint the bones by hand, a vertex group will be automatically created for them. What is a simple way to go about doing this without making them one-by-one? Ideally I wouldn't have to parent the entire armature with empty groups.

in object mode, if you select the mesh and then armature (parent of all bones), and then use Object >> Parent >> "Armature -- deform with auto weight" (or as you want "with Empty groups"  -- all is done for you.  There are many tutorials on youtube and you can search in this forum.

I know how to parent an armature with automatic or empty weights. I am asking if there's a way to create empty weights for some bones and not all of them. I am currently working on my model's hands and it would be easy to just add all the vertex groups for such a dense part all together instead of one by one. I have it parented with zero vertex groups to begin with, for the sake of not having to scroll through all the vertex groups that I'm not working on yet. If this isn't possible I imagine it would just be easier to have all the empty vertex groups to begin with.

I actually wrote a script recently for work that does a similar thing, I modified it a bit to fit your specific needs. It should work. Just run it in your script editor with Alt+P, then you should be able to search for it in your F3 operator search. If not, make sure you have Developer extras and Python tooltips enabled in Preferences -> Interface.
It's meant to be run in pose mode with at least one selected pose bone and one selected mesh object.
import bpy


def get_objects(context):
    objs_to_parent = []
    armature = None
    for obj in context.selected_objects:
        if obj.type == "MESH":
            objs_to_parent.append(obj)
        elif obj.type == "ARMATURE" and armature is None:
            armature = obj
    return armature, objs_to_parent


def main(context):
    C = context
    armature, objs = get_objects(C)
    bones = C.selected_pose_bones
    obj = objs[0]
    for bone in bones:
        vg = obj.vertex_groups.new(name=bone.name)
        
def get_obj_types(context):
    return [obj.type for obj in context.selected_objects]
        

def poll_op(context):
    types = get_obj_types(context)
    if context.mode != "POSE":
        return False
    if context.active_pose_bone is None:
        return False
    if "ARMATURE" not in types:
        return False
    if "MESH" not in types:
        return False
    if len(context.selected_objects) < 2:
        return False
    return True


class RIG_OT_quick_create_empty_vgs(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Quickly add empty vertex groups for selected bones to the selected mesh object. 
    Requires pose mode with selected bones, and a selected mesh object."""
    bl_idname = "pose.quick_create_empty_vgs"
    bl_label = "Create Empty VGs For Bones"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return poll_op(context)

    def execute(self, context):
        types = get_obj_types(context)
        if types.count("MESH") > 1:
            self.report({"ERROR"}, "Only one mesh object should be selected!")
            return {"CANCELLED"}
        main(context)
        return {"FINISHED"}
    

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RIG_OT_quick_create_empty_vgs)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RIG_OT_quick_create_empty_vgs)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

